# "Symmetric" numerical computation of second derivative

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

When numerically computing a first derivative, it is better to use

$$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + \Delta x / 2) - f(x - \Delta x / 2)}{\Delta x}$$

than to use

$$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

since it's more symmetric, and hence typically more accurate.

However, what is the equivalent of this phenomenon in the second derivative case?

In other words, the obvious candidate formula is

$$f''(x) \approx \frac{f'(x + \Delta x / 2) - f'(x - \Delta x / 2)}{\Delta x}$$

but is there a more accurate ("symmetric"?) approximation for the second derivative as is the case for the first derivative?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by inserting your first into the last equation you readily find the symmetric formula
$$
f''(x)≈\frac{f(x+Δx)−2\,f(x)+f(x-Δx)}{Δx^2}
$$
with error $O(Δx^2)$.

Comment: So you're saying it's already as symmetric as it can be? (I can't tell if it is, so that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: Yes. Time reversal, i.e., replacing $Δx$ by $-Δx$, does not change the expression.